# How to display different links in Angular depending on API result

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Angular and trying to figure out how to adapt an ASP.NET app into Angular. I need to display a different link to the user depending on the group the user belongs to. I have a Web API (ASP.NET Web API) that I can call to determine the user. I am using the following Angular code to call the Web API, but what I am unsure of is what to do next. If `$scope.userGroupInfo` contains the group the user belongs to how do I then display a different link in HTML depending on the group?

**AngularJS**

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("linkSwitcher", []);

  var MainController = function($scope, $http) {

    var onApiCallComplete= function(response) {
      $scope.userGroupInfo = response.data;
    };

    var onError = function(reason) {
      $scope.error = "There was a problem calling the API";
    };

    $scope.getUserGroup = function(userId) {
      $http.get("https://myapi.mysite.com/api/clients/getUserGroup/" + userId)
        .then(onApiCallComplete, onError); 
    };

  };

  app.controller("MainController", MainController);
}());
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <form name="GetGroup" ng-submit="getUserGroup()">
    <input type="submit" value="Lookup User Group Link" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Please assume I have referenced the Angular library properly and that I am just displaying the portion of HTML that calls the Angular script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, what do you want to change in the display? you can try using `ng-if=""` inside a tag to show it, or you can use `ng-class="someObjectMappingClassNameToBoolean"` to modify the class depending on some flag.

Ex: (I don't know the structure of your response)

```
<div ng-if="userGroupInfo.groupId=== 7" > <a>Show me if userGroupInfo.groupId equals to 7 is true!</a> </div>
```

or

```
<div ng-class="{'blue-class': userGroupInfo.isBlue === true, 'error': userGroupInfo.isError === true }" > <a>Blue class added if isBlue is true, error class if isError is true</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not even aware of the `ng-if` directive.

Comment: yeah, it removes content from the DOM if not true, so be careful with it, you could remove a controller nested below it. Nevertheless, there's lots of ways to modify the display... you can even use ng-style

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ng-href to generate a calculated hyperlink, either as a whole or just as part, e.g. ng-href="http://path.to/{{groupName}}"